# Check that all rows in numpy array are unique

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4 column array:

```
A=array([[100,1,500,1],
         [100,1,501,1],
         [101,1,501,1],
         [102,2,502,2],
         [500,1,100,1],
         [100,1,500,1],
         [502,2,102,2],
         [502,1,102,1]])
```

I want to extract the rows that are unique (or the first occurrence) and the rows such that for a row `i`, there are no other rows `j` in the array where `A[i,:]==A[j,[2,1,0,3]]` (or the first occurrence).

So for array `A`, I would like to get an array that looks like:

```
B=array([[100,1,500,1],
         [100,1,501,1],
         [101,1,501,1],
         [102,2,502,2],
         [502,1,102,1]])
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is your range of ints that you are using, or do you need this to be completely general?

Comment: Ints will go up to about 100,000.

Comment: Are the 2nd and 4th elements always equal?

Comment: Yes the 2nd and 4th element will always be equal.

Answer (score 3):

```
A[np.unique(np.sort(A,1).view("int, int, int, int"), return_index=True)[1]]
```

In steps:

```
In [385]: A
Out[385]: 
array([[100,   1, 500,   1],
       [100,   1, 501,   1],
       [101,   1, 501,   1],
       [102,   2, 502,   2],
       [500,   1, 100,   1],
       [100,   1, 500,   1],
       [502,   2, 102,   2],
       [502,   1, 102,   1]])
```

We can eliminate the need for swapping columns 0 and 2 (the thing where `A[i] = A[j, [2,1,0,3]`) simply by sorting each row. We don't have to worry about swapping columns 1 and 3, since for all rows in `A`, we have column 1 equals column 3: `A[:, 1] == A[:, 3]`.

```
In [386]: As = np.sort(A,1)

In [387]: As
Out[387]: 
array([[  1,   1, 100, 500],
       [  1,   1, 100, 501],
       [  1,   1, 101, 501],
       [  2,   2, 102, 502],
       [  1,   1, 100, 500],
       [  1,   1, 100, 500],
       [  2,   2, 102, 502],
       [  1,   1, 102, 502]])
```

Find the unique rows in `As` (the sorted array).  View it as a structured array where each row is a single element (since `np.unique` will otherwise flatten the array first)

```
In [388]: As.view('int, int, int, int')
Out[388]: 
array([[(1, 1, 100, 500)],
       [(1, 1, 100, 501)],
       [(1, 1, 101, 501)],
       [(2, 2, 102, 502)],
       [(1, 1, 100, 500)],
       [(1, 1, 100, 500)],
       [(2, 2, 102, 502)],
       [(1, 1, 102, 502)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8')])

In [389]: u, i = np.unique(As.view('int, int, int, int'), return_index=True)

In [390]: i
Out[390]: array([0, 1, 2, 7, 3])
```

And use them to get the rows that were unique in `As` from the original array `A`:

```
In [391]: A[i]
Out[391]: 
array([[100,   1, 500,   1],
       [100,   1, 501,   1],
       [101,   1, 501,   1],
       [502,   1, 102,   1],
       [102,   2, 502,   2]])
```

Comment: I get the following error:                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 178, in unique
    perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort')
TypeError: requested sort not available for type

Comment: What is `type(A)`? And `np.__version__`?

Comment: Somehow `A` has turned into an int?  It should be a numpy array.  Try splitting it up into more commands, as I'll edit to show.

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked `dtype`.  `type(A)=<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: interesting. I wonder if numpy 1.6 can't sort structured arrays?

Comment: I gave a +1 to this answer, but I think some type of explanation would be helpful too.  For example, I haven't followed the full question and example, but how about the A[i,:]==A[j,[2,1,0,3]] part?

Comment: @tom, `A[i,:]==A[j,[2,1,0,3]]` just means that row `i` matches row `j` even if columns `0` and `2` have been swapped (or not), so I just sorted each row before comparing. Since columns 1 and 3 are always the same, I can ignore the effects of shifting them around.

Answer (score 0):

For the unique rows, you can use python sets to remove duplicates. Since np arrays (or lists) are unhashable, you might have to convert rows to tuples while selecting, and then convert back to an array:

```python
B = np.array(list(set([tuple(x) for x in A])))
```

For the second part of your question, you need to implement your own selection loop:

```python
B = []
for row in A:
    lrow = list(row)
    if lrow not in B and [lrow[2], lrow[1], lrow[0], lrow[3]] not in B:
        B.append(lrow)
B = np.array(B)
```

Comment: This works well, but the only issue is that it's slow for very large arrays ~ 5,000,000 rows.  Any ideas to speed it up? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what the second part of the question means (the part that starts A[i:])  However as a simple loop you can also use

```
B = []
for data in A:
  if data not in B:
    B.append(data)
tuple(B)
```

This will now loop through A, check that it is not already in B and append it.  This is not the most efficient way to do it since you need to loop through B each time, but it is simple and obvious.

Are you asking that if data = [0, 1, 2, 3] that there does not exist a line like [2, 0, 1, 3]

if that is the case then add to the if

```
and [data[2], data[0], data[1], data[3]] not in B
```

I think that setting this up as a tree and branch processing would possibly work. That is, at A[0] create the branches by the value of A[1]. Then the branch for A[2] and the leaf at A[3}. At the final leaf, drop it if a leaf already exists. Once the tree structure has been built, go back and collect all the branches and leaves into the array structure and by definition, they will be unique. In any case, this would require reading the initial list once and would not require reading the B list fully for every row in A. I have not had time to figure out how to express this in Python rather than as a visual flow chart. Perhaps it can work as a set of dictionaries, but I am not sure.

```
{A[0]:{A[1]:{A[2]:{A[3]:True}}}}
```

would not work because it would overwrite the value for the key. Perhaps a list of dictionaries for each key and subkey would be possible, giving a set of dictionaries of the key A[1] and a list of dictionaries for the key A[2]

As each entry is read, if A[3] is not found already in a particular list, append it. If it is found, then it is a duplicate. I think that the base would be something on the order of

```
{A[0]:({A[1]:({A[2]:(A[3])})})}
```

I do not know if this concept would work or not, but would require the appropriate for loops and appends and might be too complex to set up.

Comment: Yeah you got the second part.  This works, but the only issue is that it's slow for very large arrays ~ 5,000,000 rows.  Any ideas to speed it up? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3357979 Perhaps a dictionary of lists of dictionaries might allow a tree and branch method. Then again maybe not. I do not have the time to actually analyze it properly or try to build the code.